# Как настроить А-record на выделеном сервере?

Tags: dns, vps, vds

Куплен домен, а сервер в другом месте.
У регистратора прописал NS провайдера серверов.
Как поменять A-запись на сервере?
На сервере debian 9
Вот ответ от тех. поддержки 
"Then the A record has to be updated in your dedicated server."

Answer (score 1):

DNS Hosting - это отдельный сервис. Теоретически ты сам можешь настроить и запустить *authoritative DNS server* на своем выделенном сервере, но, судя по твоему вопросу (т.е. уровню знаний по этому вопросу), это будет плохая идея.

Поэтому тебе лучше воспользоваться услугами профессионалов. DNS Hosting часто можно купить у твоего регистрара (компании, где ты купил сам домен), или у независимого хостера. Некоторые регистрары даже предлагают этот сервис своим клиентам бесплатно.

Когда ты определишься с сервисом DNS Hosting, обращайся в их службу поддержки и рассказывай им, какой A-Record тебе нужен.